# SQL Server : list connections to database without VIEW SERVER STATE permission

Tags: sql-server, connection

For an application I need to see how many sessions are using the database for the current logged in user. The table `sys.dm_exec_sessions` allows me to retrieve this data, however:

- this contains data for all the logged in users, I only need information about the user which is currently logged in
- this requires either the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission, or some workarounds which requires the database to be marked as trustworthy. Both permission flags are not possible situation.

I expected the `VIEW DATABASE STATE` permission to be sufficient to view the sessions for a certain database (not server). However, if a user is granted this permission, only one record (the current session) is displayed when querying the `sys.dm_exec_sessions` database.

I somehow expected this permission to let me retrieve all the connections for the current logged in user instead of all the users, but it does not.

**Question**

Is there anything I can do without granting the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission or marking the database as TRUSTWORTHY? I am able to obtain the `VIEW DATABASE STATE` permission, but this either does not work or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Since the MS Docs clearly state that these are the permissions needed - **NO**, you cannot view the contents of the **system view** (it's a **view** - not a table) without these permissions ......

Comment: @marc_s The docs also state that VIEW DATABASE STATE should work as well, but I can't get it to work using that permission flag either.

Comment: The SQL Server documentation is a bit confusing - it says 
> SQL Database: Requires VIEW DATABASE STATE to see all connections to the current database. 
However, this appears to mean Azure SQL Database, not a database within a server